# Item could not be retrieved: Unknown Error. Please contact support. Heroku nodejs

Tags: node.js, heroku

getting an error **Item could not be retrieved: Unknown Error. Please contact support** while trying to view the logs of my nodejs application.
[image: Application logs on heroku]

it's my free heroku application. Someone can please help me that how can I again enable my application logs.